# Is there any writing trick for typing css property and value faster in vscode?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

in html when we wanna type `tag` with `classes` we type `div.example-1` the output will automatically `<div class"example-1">`

is there any similar trick in CSS when we wanna write `property` and the `value`?

thank you :)

Comment: if vscode has support for emmet code (which that shorthand html looks like) you can do stuff like: type `bbrr` and hit tab for `border-bottom-right-radius`, I [found this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) which should help you out.

Comment: @Dale I think it [supports emmet code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) haven't tested it, so I have no idea if that will work or not

Comment: @Dale thank youuuuuu so muchhhhhhhhhhh :)))))

Comment: I love emmet code, enjoy :)